# Retrieve data from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working with this coding like a week ago. But I got stuck at retrieve part. So, I have these 8 textboxes for expenses, and 8 more for price for each expense. At that page, there's a dropdown menu which user will select month, then the expenses for that month e.g January, the textboxes will show the records from db for that month. How to link the month so that it can retrieve the data from db based on user's records? and how to show only current login user's records? Thanks for heelp me guys.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ExpTab WHERE UserID = @UserName and month = @month",  conn); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@month", DropDownList2.SelectedValue));
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

just wanna ask you huys, how to show the retrieved data in the textboxes? Thankk you

Comment: Does your db has any date column?

Comment: I thinks its better if your post the DB schema as well

Comment: have you tried debugging it ? what it returns ?  user SQL profiler

Comment: still working on it. I dont know how to load the retrieve data in textbox.

Comment: textbox1.Text = dt.rows[0].cells[i].Value; and so on for all textboxes, allthough usually datatable is displayed in grid.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the user selects the month from a dropdown list instead of a calendar control, you would do something like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings    ["Connection"].ConnectionString))
    {
      conn.Open(); //you were missing this
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ExpTab WHERE UserID = @UserName and month(date_column)=@month",  conn);
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserName", 
      HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@month", dropDownDate.SelectedValue));
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());//load the data in a data table, for example.
    }
}
```

Above code makes the following assumptions:

1. You have a column in the `ExpTab` table that holds a datetime; therefore this: `... and month(date_col)` will match the number of the month you are interested in.
2. Your month selection comes from a dropdown called `dropDownDate` that assigns each month a integer value from 1 to 12.
3. My code does not take into account year. I'll let you figure out that part.

Link to the [MONTH function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Hi, I almost got there. Just wanna ask you, how to load the data in textbox? Thank you

Comment: Just iterate through the rows of the DataTable variable (dt). Use a foreach loop like: *foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) ...* then assign the values from the particular column of the datarow to the txtfield.